# Find all entries that contain more than one colon character

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find all entries that contain more than one colon (`:`) character.

However when I do `LIKE %:%` it shows the entire table because of `http://`. How can I find more than one colon?

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `downloads` 
WHERE  `url` LIKE  '%:%'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: colon character in what? a column? please be more specific

Comment: and please show the whole code that you are using

Comment: What is your RDBMS ? Oracle ? MySQL ? PostgreSQL ? MSSQL ? Tag your question properly.

Comment: Added my code, i have some downloads that have a colon character that i need to find and replace as windows can't save filenames with colon in them

Comment: Is this a MySQL database?

Comment: "It shows the entire database"? Surely that's not what you mean

Comment: Out on a limb here, but maybe all records are being shown because you're looking for `:` in a `url` column which presumably starts with `http://` - if every record has the `url` column populated, then the query is doing what it's supposed to.

Comment: Yeah when i run that query it returns everything in the database. I want to find just URLs that have a colon in them

Comment: if the URLs are absolute, then they will all have a colon character in the scheme, e.g. `http://`

Comment: It can't possibly show everything in the database, everything from the `downloads` table is what you mean

Comment: @HoneyBadger Oh, i feel stupid now lol. Is there a way to find more than 1 colon?

Comment: `LIKE %:%:%` is probably what you want - you may need to tweak it though.

Comment: You can escape the http colon by using `substring`. Better yet, do what Brian said.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll Thank you so much! Sorry for not putting the right info in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find a colon that occurs after the scheme of your URL, then change your LIKE clause accordingly:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `downloads` 
WHERE  `url` LIKE  '%:%:%'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

The first colon will be in your scheme, and the second will be somewhere else in the Url after the scheme.

A word of caution, however - it is completely valid to have a colon in the Url when a port number is specified, e.g.: `http://localhost:8080`

Comment: This worked great for me.